# Having trouble updating int label but can update string label fine

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm sure someone is going to mark this as a duplicate the second I post it, but I assure you, I've been looking for hours. I'm brand new to tkinter so bear with me as I'd like a really straightforward answer if possible. Anything related to this specifically was a bit complex for me right now and I didn't feel it answered my question.

I know how to have a Label update with textvariable and StringVar. However, I'm trying to **update an integer** and I can't seem to figure it out for some reason. The number updates and prints through the console but I can't figure out the right syntax to get it to show up on the interface. It either just shows 0 (as the default variable shows) or there is no text there at all depending on what I've changed the code to)

So all I'm doing is simply **incrementing a number**. Let's leave it at that for now. And if anyone has any resources to more straightforward documentation please let me know because it seems tkinter in general is pretty obscure in documentation online as far as I can tell.

```
my_count = 0

def increase_mycount():
    global my_count
    increment = int(my_count) + 1
    my_count = str(increment)
    print(my_count)

Label(root, textvariable=my_count).grid(row=2, column=1)
Button(root, text="+", command=inc_mycount).grid(row=3, column=2)
```

This is where it's at right now, I've tried changing my_count into an IntVar and also a StringVar and I get an error saying I can't use + with int and intvar or int with stringvar

Is there something really simple I'm missing? I'm struggling finding comprehensive documentation on tkinter. It's easy to find Python information but not this really.. I'm in the process of organizing all the info I'd like into some google docs.

Thank you for any time you give. This seems like it should be a really simple thing to do but I've only worked with engines that update things for me. I'm only use tkinter, a .py file, and cmd for this.

And another note, I can't use .set() for this either it seems, like I could for a string. So I'm just struggling with the syntax unless there is a different method for numbers on labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use one of tkinter's variable objects when using `textvariable`. In this case, `IntVar`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

my_count = tk.IntVar()

def increase_mycount():
    current = my_count.get()
    my_count.set(current+1)

tk.Label(root, textvariable=my_count).grid(row=2, column=1)
tk.Button(root, text="+", command=increase_mycount).grid(row=3, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I haven't seen that formatting before now.